# SwiftUI VIEW change variable from external class

Tags: variables, swiftui, state

A similar question was asked before, and with the help of several netizens, some codes have been changed.

When press .. "Show Next View" >> "Change-Me" >> "Return" .. why the variable "price" can not change to 9 ....

I am a novice, I know there code have something wrong I can't find it and hope someone can guide me, Thanks!

```
class ExtenalClass {
    let SubFrutis = ContentView()
   
    func ExtChangePrice() {
        SubFrutis.fChangePrice()
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var price: Int = 0
    @State var vPresent = false
    
    func fChangePrice() {
       price = 9
        print("Price Value is: \(String(price))")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(price)).padding()
            Button("Show Next View") { self.vPresent = true }
                .sheet(isPresented: $vPresent) {
                    SecondView(vPresent: self.$vPresent)
                }.padding()
            
            Button("Add-Me") { price += 1 }.padding()
            Button("RESET") { price = 1 }.padding()
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var vPresent: Bool
    
    var vExtenal = ExtenalClass()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Change-Me") {
            vExtenal.ExtChangePrice()
//            ContentView().fChangePrice()
        }.padding()
        Button("Return") { self.vPresent = false }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never store a View inside a class like this (SubFrutis). You also shouldn’t be referencing a class without a property wrapper like you’re doing with vExternal. This is probably a great opportunity to go through some SwiftUI tutorials and learn the basics of the framework.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). You are likely coming from some other language/ui framework. SwiftUI is not like the others, your approach is conceptually incorrect.

Comment: Can give an example to list how to change a variable ("price" for this example) in a View from an External CLASS (Not from another View)

Comment: That is an anti-pattern in SwiftUI. If you want to access shared state like this, it should be stored in a shared class or parent `View` -- not in the child `View`.